# Is a buffer char array always stored in stack?

Tags: buffer-overflow

All the example problems in my text book show buffer arrays being stored in stack, and this causing problems when the return address is overwritten. However, is a buffer always in stack? I assumed an array would be written somewhere else in memory and not the stack.

Comment: Welcome to IS Stack Exchange. Some more information would be useful, such as what programming language you are using because different languages and even different compilers may treat the storage of variables in arrays very differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local variable buffers that are declared as a constant size (see the below example), or initialized immediately are stored on the stack.

`char x[20];` or `char x[] = "this buffer";`

Even if they are then passed to a function the variable will remain stored on the stack.  Just farther up from the executed function.

If you allocate memory for a buffer then it will be stored in heap memory rather than on the stack.

`char *x = (char *) malloc(LENGTH_OF_BUFFER);`

This is when [heap spraying](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/12/31/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-11-heap-spraying-demystified/) may become necessary for exploitation.  The reason you see most example buffer overflows on the stack is because it's the easiest way to begin to understand the concepts of exploitation.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer arrays are *usually* stored on the stack.  However, it's quite possible to store them on the heap or in fixed memory locations -- and that's all assuming that you're dealing with a language (and architecture) that distinguishes stack and heap.

Answer (score 1):

It depends primarily on the compiler, where your buffered is declared and how functions are called.

In C, generally speaking, local variables are allocated on the stack as well as some of the parameters provided to function calls (in cdecl calling convention[*](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml). Other calling conventions might push some parameters through registers or even through transparent heap allocation in some cases).

Some languages and compilers will allocate these differently. For instance, in Delphi, is you declare a local variable of type "string", the actual data will be stored on the heap, with only a pointer allocated to the stack.

Finally, a programmer can always decide to explicitly allocate buffers on the heap (or global memory).